# Why the prism _Show does not work for a list?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

How to explain the 3rd result? Why is the returned list empty?

```hs
>[Just 1, Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]^..folded._Just
[1,2,3]

>"1"^?_Show::Maybe Int
Just 1

>["1", "2", "x"]^..folded._Show :: [Maybe Int]
[]
```

`_Just` and `_Show` are prisms:

```
>:t _Just
_Just :: Prism (Maybe a) (Maybe b) a b
>:t _Show
_Show :: (Read a, Show a) => Prism' String a
```

But `_Show` does not work as I would expect. How to get the result `[Just 1, Just 2]` with lens/prisms? Sure, I can use `to readMaybe` but I thought I can use existing prism instead of the helper `to`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`["1", "2", "x"]^..folded._Show :: [Maybe Int]` tries to read each element as `Maybe Int`, so the list needs to be something like `["Just 1", "Just 2", "x"]`.

You can parse each element as `Int`, then wrap it in `Just` to get `[Just 1, Just 2]`.

```
["1", "2", "x"] ^.. folded . _Show @Int . re _Just
```